# Please explain the void loop() section of the sketch

Tags: sketch

```cpp
#include <VirtualWire.h>

int PWMB = 5; //Speed control

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //receiver setup
  vw_set_rx_pin(2);  
  vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); 
  vw_setup(2000);
  vw_rx_start();
}

void loop(){
  uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN]; 
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
  {
    int i;
    int column = 0;
    String message;
    int commands[30];

    for (i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
    { 
      //DEBUG:
      Serial.print(char(buf[i]));

      if(char(buf[i]) == '|'){
        commands[column] = message.toInt();
        message = "";
        column++;
      } else {
        message += char(buf[i]);
      }
    }

  commands[column] = message.toInt();
  }
}
```

This topic is the receiver side of my last topic: [please explain the sketch attached](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62576/please-explain-the-sketch-attached/62579?noredirect=1#comment134324_62579)
that one sending date and this is a receiver.

questions:

1. The transmitter transfer date array of [60] like: 523 | 487, here `int commands[30];` just 30, is it OK?
2. `if(char(buf[i]) == '|') / commands[column] = message.toInt();`, seems just convert the date before '|'?
3. What is the result of `message += char(buf[i]);`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The transmitter transfer date array of [60] like: 523 | 487, here " int commands[30];" just 30, is it OK?

If you have a maximum of 59 characters (59 printable characters plus the NULL at the end equals 60), and each number is separated by a `|` character, then the maximum possible numbers you can have, if they are all single digit, is 30. So yes, an array of 30 integers is fine.

> " if(char(buf[i]) == '|') / commands[column] = message.toInt();", seems just convert the date before '|'?

Yes. It takes whatever has been placed in `message` and converts it to an integer, then empties `message` ready for the next number.

> what is the result of " message += char(buf[i]);"? Thanks

It adds the current character from the buffer (pointed to by `i`) to the end of the `message` string.

It's not the best way of doing it, and it can make a mess of your heap causing your Arduino to crash after a while.

Personally I would use `strtok()` directly on the buffer:

```
int i = 0;
char *part = strtok(buffer, "|");
while (part) {
    command[i] = atoi(part);
    i++;
    part = strtok(NULL, "|");
}
```

This of course assumes that `buffer` is properly NULL terminated.

Comment: @ Majenko♦ Thank you Majenko♦, would you please ref to: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62576/please-explain-the-sketch-attached/62579?noredirect=1#comment134324_62579 and see what's the date sent? and see if there are match?